# MvcSiteMapNode that doesn't have controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

My site should print the following menu:

- Customers (none link)

  - List /Customers/Index
  - New  /Customers/New

The root menu should not be any link, it's just a container to hold the actual submenus.
Can this be accomplish with mvcSiteMap?

I tried the following, but the "List" is never the CurrentNode. "Customers" always get the IsCurrentNode and I can't apply the write css because of that:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" visibility="MenuHelper,!*">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customers" controller="Customer" action="Index" area="Admin" clickable="false" description="Todos os clientes cadastrados" cssClass="icon-group">
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="List" action="Index" description="Todos os clientes cadastrados"/>
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="the customers" action="Details" preservedRouteParameters="customerId" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*"/>
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="New" action="New" />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove "Index" from the non-clickable grouping node so it is never matched. Basically, you have 2 nodes with the exact same route signature here:

area="Admin"
controller="Customer"
action="Index"

The first one that matches in the SiteMap always wins. So if you remove "Index" from the first one (you can because it is non-clickable, so all of the route settings are ignored on that node but can still be inherited), it will never be matched as long as you have a default action configured in your routes.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" visibility="MenuHelper,!*">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Customers" controller="Customer" area="Admin" clickable="false" description="Todos os clientes cadastrados" cssClass="icon-group">
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="List" action="Index" description="Todos os clientes cadastrados"/>
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="the customers" action="Details" preservedRouteParameters="customerId" visibility="SiteMapPathHelper,!*"/>
   <mvcSiteMapNode title="New" action="New" />
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```